# log4j JDBCAppender create tables on demand

Tags: log4j

Some time ago, I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325141/log4j-jdbcappender-rotate-table-name) about how to get log rotaion from JDBCAppender.

It turned out to be rather easy to get JDBCAppender to switch to a new table at the start of each month, so that the old table could be dumped, archived and deleted.

The problem now, is that I now want to rotate the logs daily, and creating a new logging table by hand each day would be a pain. I know that I could write a simple perl script to run from cron each day, but I would prefer not to have another component to go wrong, which could get forgotten when a new instance of the platform is setup.

So far the only solution I can think of is to subclass JDBCAppender to give it the ability to create tables as required, but I wondered if anyone else had any solutions in this area.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried it already, why not use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)?

It is a Java based scheduler similar to cron that you can easily integrate in your application. Just configure it in such a way that it performs necessary database table housekeeping every day at midnight (or some other predefined time).

This way, you have no external dependencies and you don't have to subclass JDBCAppender.