# How to create Sequence of Tables dynamically in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have create log tables generated daily, which has massive amount of data. If I have add data in single table, then the size of table will be very big.

Is there a way to create sequence of tables automatically depending on the day to store logs in hibernate and dynamically bind them to class.

Example - Log_20180101, Log_20180102, ....

Edit: l don't generate these logs. These are web access logs generated from another server. I want to store valid log from it and want analyse it.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not a good idea to use hibernate for this usecase nor is it a good idea to use RDBMS for this usecase.

You may want to look at log4j jdbc appender if you want to go with RDBMS.

[log4j JDBCAppender rotate table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325141/log4j-jdbcappender-rotate-table-name)

You will have to create the tables yourself. Hibernate cannot do such mapping.

Comment: agree. BTW log should be lighweight and simple to the possible level (safe, resistant to errors).

Comment: if you are in log analysis business, you can use better suited databases like elastic search or cassandra. They scale horizontally and you would not have to worry about rotation. Even if you want to stick with RDBMS, atleast have a look at ELK stack, just for some ideas.